# シェーダーがコンパイル出来ない　構文エラーの解決法が知りたい

Tags: directx

fxc.exeコンパイラです。dxLibに使うバイナリシェーダーをコンパイルしたいのですがエラーの解決法がわからず困っています。このエラーはどうすればいいのでしょうか？ピクセルシェーダーと頂点シェーダー二つに分けています。

(43,14-34): error X4541: vertex shader must minimally write all four components of POSITION
日本語google翻訳 頂点シェーダーは、POSITIONの4つのコンポーネントすべてを最小限に書き込む必要があります。

このエラーはどうすればいいのでしょうか？ピクセルシェーダーコードです。下の提示コード

```
//頂点シェーダー.hlsl
struct VS_Input
{
    // 座標( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の pos の値 )
    float3 Position        : POSITION0 ;

    // 補助座標( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の spos の値 )
    float4 SubPosition     : POSITION1 ;

    // 法線( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の norm の値 )
    float3 Normal          : NORMAL0 ;

    // 接線( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の tan の値 )
    float3 Tangent         : TANGENT ;

    // 従法線( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の binorm の値 )
    float3 Binormal        : BINORMAL0 ;

    // ディフューズカラー( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の dif の値 )
    float4 DiffuseColor    : COLOR0 ;

    // スペキュラカラー( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の spc の値 )
    float4 SpecularColor   : COLOR1 ;

    // テクスチャ座標０( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の u, v の値 )
    float2 TextureCoord0   : TEXCOORD0 ;

    // テクスチャ座標１( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の su, sv の値 )
    float2 TextureCoord1   : TEXCOORD1 ;
} ;


// 頂点シェーダーの出力
struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 dif         : COLOR0 ;       // ディフューズカラー
    float2 texCoords0  : TEXCOORD0 ;    // テクスチャ座標
    float4 pos         : SV_POSITION ;  // 座標( プロジェクション空間 )
} ;

// 基本パラメータ
struct DX_D3D11_VS_CONST_BUFFER_BASE
{
    float4      AntiViewportMatrix[ 4 ] ;               // アンチビューポート行列
    float4      ProjectionMatrix[ 4 ] ;                 // ビュー　→　プロジェクション行列
    float4      ViewMatrix[ 3 ] ;                       // ワールド　→　ビュー行列
    float4      LocalWorldMatrix[ 3 ] ;                 // ローカル　→　ワールド行列

    float4      ToonOutLineSize ;                       // トゥーンの輪郭線の大きさ
    float       DiffuseSource ;                         // ディフューズカラー( 0.0f:マテリアル  1.0f:頂点 )
    float       SpecularSource ;                        // スペキュラカラー(   0.0f:マテリアル  1.0f:頂点 )
    float       MulSpecularColor ;                      // スペキュラカラー値に乗算する値( スペキュラ無効処理で使用 )
    float       Padding ;
} ;

// その他の行列
struct DX_D3D11_VS_CONST_BUFFER_OTHERMATRIX
{
    float4      ShadowMapLightViewProjectionMatrix[ 3 ][ 4 ] ;          // シャドウマップ用のライトビュー行列とライト射影行列を乗算したもの
    float4      TextureMatrix[ 3 ][ 2 ] ;                               // テクスチャ座標操作用行列
} ;

// 基本パラメータ
cbuffer cbD3D11_CONST_BUFFER_VS_BASE            : register( b1 )
{
    DX_D3D11_VS_CONST_BUFFER_BASE               g_Base ;
} ;

// その他の行列
cbuffer cbD3D11_CONST_BUFFER_VS_OTHERMATRIX     : register( b2 )
{
    DX_D3D11_VS_CONST_BUFFER_OTHERMATRIX        g_OtherMatrix ;
} ;



// main関数
VS_OUTPUT main( VS_INPUT VSInput )
{
    VS_OUTPUT VSOutput ;
    float4 lLocalPosition ;
    float4 lWorldPosition ;
    float4 lViewPosition ;


    // 頂点座標変換 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++( 開始 )

    // ローカル座標のセット
    lLocalPosition.xyz = VSInput.pos ;
    lLocalPosition.w = 1.0f ;

    // 座標計算( ローカル→ビュー→プロジェクション )
    lWorldPosition.x = dot( lLocalPosition, g_Base.LocalWorldMatrix[ 0 ] ) ;
    lWorldPosition.y = dot( lLocalPosition, g_Base.LocalWorldMatrix[ 1 ] ) ;
    lWorldPosition.z = dot( lLocalPosition, g_Base.LocalWorldMatrix[ 2 ] ) ;
    lWorldPosition.w = 1.0f ;

    lViewPosition.x = dot( lWorldPosition, g_Base.ViewMatrix[ 0 ] ) ;
    lViewPosition.y = dot( lWorldPosition, g_Base.ViewMatrix[ 1 ] ) ;
    lViewPosition.z = dot( lWorldPosition, g_Base.ViewMatrix[ 2 ] ) ;
    lViewPosition.w = 1.0f ;

    VSOutput.pos.x = dot( lViewPosition, g_Base.ProjectionMatrix[ 0 ] ) ;
    VSOutput.pos.y = dot( lViewPosition, g_Base.ProjectionMatrix[ 1 ] ) ;
    VSOutput.pos.z = dot( lViewPosition, g_Base.ProjectionMatrix[ 2 ] ) ;
    VSOutput.pos.w = dot( lViewPosition, g_Base.ProjectionMatrix[ 3 ] ) ;

    // 頂点座標変換 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++( 終了 )



    // 出力パラメータセット ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++( 開始 )

    VSOutput.texCoords0 = VSInput.texCoords0 ;
    VSOutput.dif = VSInput.DiffuseColor ;

    // 出力パラメータセット ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++( 終了 )


    // 出力パラメータを返す
    return VSOutput ;
}






   // ピクセルシェーダーの入力 .hlsl
      struct VS_INPUT
     {
    // 座標( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の pos の値 )
    float3 Position        : POSITION0 ;

    // 補助座標( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の spos の値 )
    float4 SubPosition     : POSITION1 ;

    // 法線( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の norm の値 )
    float3 Normal          : NORMAL0 ;

    // 接線( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の tan の値 )
    float3 Tangent         : TANGENT ;

    // 従法線( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の binorm の値 )
    float3 Binormal        : BINORMAL0 ;

    // ディフューズカラー( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の dif の値 )
    float4 DiffuseColor    : COLOR0 ;

    // スペキュラカラー( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の spc の値 )
    float4 SpecularColor   : COLOR1 ;

    // テクスチャ座標０( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の u, v の値 )
    float2 TextureCoord0   : TEXCOORD0 ;

    // テクスチャ座標１( VERTEX3DSHADER構造体の su, sv の値 )
    float2 TextureCoord1   : TEXCOORD1 ;
} ;



// ピクセルシェーダーの出力
struct PS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 color0           : COLOR0;   // 色
    float3 pos : POSITION;
} ;


// main関数
PS_OUTPUT main( VS_INPUT PSInput ) 
{
    PS_OUTPUT PSOutput;


    PSOutput.color0 = PSInput.DiffuseColor;
    PSOutput.pos = PSInput.Position;


    // 出力パラメータを返す
    return PSOutput ;
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問する際は fxc.exe に渡しているコンパイルオプションを完全に提示してください。
シェーダーのコンパイルに使用しているシェーダープロファイル（シェーダーモデル）は何ですか？

ピクセルシェーダーをコンパイルする際は `ps_?_?` を指定しますが、
おそらく間違って頂点シェーダーのプロファイル `vs_?_?` を指定しているのではないかと思います。

- [Syntax - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dtools/dx-graphics-tools-fxc-syntax)

fxc.exe はシェーダーモデル5.1までサポートしていますが、使用可能なプロファイルはDirect3D APIのバージョン (9.0, 9.0c, 10.x, 11.x, 12) および実行環境のグラフィックスハードウェアやデバイスドライバーの対応度によって異なります。

- [Shader Models vs Shader Profiles - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-models)